# Como abro el cmd sin interfaz (acceso directo)

Tags: cmd

Necesito que un codigo se ejecute cada vez que enciendo mi pc, pero para esto necesito de que la CMD no aparezca en pantalla, es decir como si se ejecutara en modo silencioso o algo por el estilo, en segundo plano para especificar He puesto mi Acceso directo en "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\RPC.ink" ¿Que tengo que añadir aqui? para que se abra en segundo plano el CMD y no tenga que cerrar

[image: Propiedades del archivo de acceso directo]

Me ayudaria muchisimo, gracias.

Comment: puedes descargar bat to exe converter portable y hacer que se ejecute en modo silencioso o usa powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que para eso necesitas un archivo **batch** y usar la extensión **.vbs**, todos los archivos con esta extensión funcionan en segundo plano. Guardar tu archivo con extensión **.vbs** y añade este código con tus especificaciones.

```
set objshell = createobject("wscript.shell")
objshell.run "archivo.cmd",vbhide
```